# Email Signature

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, email-alert

I have one scenarios like, have configured out going email setting under "My Email Settings" and there i have mentioned a signature.

Now i also have one visualforce email template with a different signature and when i send a email to someone with that VF template getting two signature.

So, here i wanted to know that is there anyway to avoid pasting default signature in case of using VF template?

### --

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No or at least not as standard if they have the signature populated.

If you have a Signature defined it's getting inserted and with the new release (Summer '15) in the Email Publisher (not the Email Author, old standard email tool) the signature is now appended in your reply automatically and you can choose if it appears at the very end of the whole chain or at the end of the context of the current reply (above all other content). - http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_e2c_user_signature.htm

So what I'd propose if you are going to be defining signatures in templates is perhaps create a custom field on the user object where you users can define a custom signature and from here in your template logic check if this is populated and use either the default signature you include on your template or their custom signature field when sending the email.